# (temporarily)using and learning ruby on rails without internet

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, railstutorial.org

So I'm about to leave for africa for 2 weeks where i will for the most part not have an internet connection, during which i am going to start learning ruby on rails so that i can implement it in the social network i am going to start building when i get back. Im planning on saving the tutorials from rubyonrails.org to my computer before i go so that i can still use them but it seems like almost all of them are dependent on me being able to download files from the internet(for example won't "$ rails new blog" pull that info from the rails server?), **does anyone know of a way i could use ruby (in particularly these tutorials) without the internet (like maybe i just need to pre-install a bunch of gems or something?)**

I have basically no experience with rails so sorry if my interpretation of ruby and these tutorials is incorrect.

Comment: Install Ruby and install rails and get a book with you.. Now you can read offline Rails...

Comment: this is the topic of blog posts, not a SO Q&A format like this.  FYI.  Travel safe.

Comment: I would download the docs for my combination of Ruby and Ruby on Rails from [rubydocs](https://rubydocs.org/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Theoretically, yes, practically, no.  Sure, you can fire up a local web server and write code, but you obviously don't want to write everything yourself, you want to take advantage of ruby's gem package system.  This will, obviously require an internet connection.

Comment: yea that was my thought exactly, i was hoping that there might be a list, or even a bundle install that might quickly get me the all the gems i might need to practice with.

Comment: I would look up Micheal Hartl's "The Ruby On Rails Tutorial" it's available online for free and in PDF format.  Then look here for the Rails 4 code https://github.com/railstutorial/sample_app_rails_4.  Git clone it and run `bundle install`.  That will give you most of the Gems that you need, but ONLY for that Rails app.  If you find that you need anything else, well, you're out of luck.